# How do I read a file and write its data to another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read from file named as `original.txt`, in that file I have to read `YAL013w` and `YGL127c` which are 1st and 3rd field, which is divided by `|` in the file.

Example data:

```
YAL013w|DEP1|YGL127c|SOH1|DNA repair|
```

Then I have to make another file named as DNA repair which is the 5th field of the line and I have to put  `YAL013w` and `YGL127c` in the new file. I have to do it by python, please help me.

Comment: An example would make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('original.txt') as f:
    row = next(f).split('|') # => ['YAL013w', 'DEP1', 'YGL127c', 'SOH1', 'DNA repair', '\n']
    filename = row[4]
    with open(filename, 'w') as f2:
        f2.write('{}|{}\n'.format(row[0], row[2]))
```

---

```
>>> 'YAL013w|DEP1|YGL127c|SOH1|DNA repair|\n'.split('|')
['YAL013w', 'DEP1', 'YGL127c', 'SOH1', 'DNA repair', '\n']
>>> row = 'YAL013w|DEP1|YGL127c|SOH1|DNA repair|\n'.split('|')
>>> row[4]
'DNA repair'
```

See [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.split).